# Can I use String Interpolation in Angular with cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a component that called few times and each time generates a button, where I need to click this button that in this component. The problem is that cypress tells me there are multiple buttons. Using `eq(1) / eq(2)` doesn't work for me for some reasons.

My question is, let's say I have a public variable in the ts class, for example:

```
public index: number;
```

Can I do something like:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" data-cy="myButton{{index}}"
```

Then in the spec file to do:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=myButton1]').click()
cy.get('[data-cy=myButton2]').click()
```

etc.

Thanks.

Comment: In case if you don't give the index and your html stays `<button type="button" id="myBtn" data-cy="myButton"`. can you check whether you get all buttons if you execute `$$('[data-cy=myButton]')` in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

It seems String Interpolation wouldn't work with `data-cy`

I used instead `id="myBtn{{index}}"`, so I can do

```
cy.get('[data-cy=myButton1]').click()
cy.get('[data-cy=myButton2]').click()
```

Comment: In the test you should use:
cy.get('#myButton1').click()
cy.get('#myButton2').click()